# ionic cordova build android - Ionic Woocommerce app not build

Tags: ionic-framework, woocommerce, ionic3, ionic-native, woocommerce-rest-api

[Ionic cordova build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vRfP.png)

Command

```
cordova build android
```

Gives output:

> Android Studio project detected
>   ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Clide\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
>   JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191
>   studio
>   Subproject Path: CordovaLib
>   Subproject Path: app
>   Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use `--status` for details
>   `publishNonDefault` is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
>   **[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.**
>
> `cordova build android` exited with exit code 1.
>
> Re-running this command with the `--verbose` flag may provide more information.

Comment: It says: run `cordova build android --verbose` to get more info, have you done it?

Comment: ionic Cordova platform remove android and ionic Cordova build android, then I find onesignal error, after onesignal updating, android build properly